# fetching wsdl with Savon on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, soap, savon

I'm using Savon to connect to a SOAP API. the wsdl is there :
    https://ws-rec.sivin.fr/sivin/services/WS_SiVin_Consulter?wsdl

Everything works fine locally.
When I push my app onto heroku, I get an exception :

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - 'https://ws-rec.sivin.fr/sivin/services/WS_SiVin_Consulter?wsdl'
```

any idea ?

Comment: Perhaps it was only temporarily off the DNS?

Comment: nope, that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it was just a config error in the environment variable in heroku. I added single quotes around the url.